# How to use jackcess to connect to a Microsoft Access database (.accdb)?

Tags: java, database-connection

I have a Microsoft Access database file that I'd like to use it in Ubuntu.

I know that I can access it using Jackcess. I have downloaded the jackcess-2.0.6.jar file but I don't know how to use it? Please give me some hints about where to put the jar file.

Further, a sample code snippet explaining how to use Jackcess would be appreciated. since I don't know what package should I import. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't quite implemented/used jackcess yet. But to use External jars, like in eclipse you need to right click "JRE System Library" in your project.
Build path >> Configure Build Path & then use the Button "Add external JARs" to browse and finally import your jar file.

Then you can create a program by the use of its classes & methods, without any error of unknown class.